# ld: undefined reference to object I can see in objdump

Tags: c++, g++, ld, d

I am doing some unorthodox linking right now and predictably enough I encountered some issues.
However I have gone through all the usual subjects and the problem persists.
I have a D source file defining a class

```
extern (C++){
    class motionFactory{
        public:
            this(double velocity, double gravity, double angle){
                this.velocity = velocity;
                this.gravity = gravity;
                this.angle = angle;
            }
     }
}
```

That I then access in C++ using this .hpp file (according to the [D documentation](https://dlang.org/spec/cpp_interface.html#using_d_classes_from_cpp) this is perfectly legal)

```
class motionFactory {
    public:
        motionFactory(double velocity, double gravity, double angle);
}
```

And then inherit from this class like this:

```
class motionGraph : public wxBitmap, public motionFactory{
    public:
        motionGraph(double velocity, double gravity, double angle, int width, int height);
}
```

During compilation however I encounter a link error stating that the constructor for motionFactory is undefined.

```
/usr/bin/ld: motionGraph.o: in function `motionGraph::motionGraph(double, double, double, int, int)':
motionGraph.cpp:(.text+0x66): undefined reference to `motionFactory::motionFactory(double, double, double)'
```

I compile like this:

```
gdc -r D/motion.d ballistics.o -o motion.o $(CFLAGS) -lgphobos -J fortran
g++ -c gui/motionGraph.cpp -o motionGraph.o $(CFLAGS) $(wxFlags)
g++ gui/main.cpp motionGraph.o motion.o mainFrame.o -o guiCalculator -lm $(CFLAGS) $(wxFlags)
```

I find this quite weird because in previous versions of the code I was constructing motionFactories in c++ just fine, and what's more objdump says that the constructor is there

compiled D file objdump:

```
000000000000039c g     F .text  0000000000000047 motionFactory::motionFactory(double, double, double)
```

compiled c++ file objdump:

```
0000000000000000 g     F .text  0000000000000177 motionGraph::motionGraph(double, double, double, int, int)
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 motionFactory::motionFactory(double, double, double)
0000000000000000  w    O .data.rel.ro._ZTV11motionGraph 0000000000000108 vtable for motionGraph
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 operator new(unsigned long)
0000000000000000         *UND*  0000000000000000 motionFactory::motionFactory(double, double, double)
```

How come objdump sees the constructor and yet g++ doesn't?
I know I am making things unnecessarily hard for myself but please I'm lost.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the D documentation, as your code is not like the code in the documentation's example.

Comment: Indeed it is different. Instead of inheriting a single method i inherit the constructor, additionally instead of wrapping just the method definition in extern I wrapped the entire class. I can't exactly see what difference that makes since c++ had no issues finding the constructor when creating a new instance via new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.
C++ was expecting to see different constructors for different levels of multi inheritance.
D didn't provide those since it has no concept of multi inheritance.
Which caused the weird errors.
Writing a custom link script to rename the calls fixed the problem.